# How could I add a WHERE condition to code with INNER JOINs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, where-clause

I don't know how to add a where condition for an AS column, is there a

I've tried using the column with square brackets and it doesn't work

```
SELECT   
    Suppliers.CompanyName,
    SUM([Order Details].UnitPrice*Quantity) AS [Total sales]
FROM
    [Order Details]  
INNER JOIN 
    Products ON products.ProductID = [Order Details].ProductID
INNER JOIN 
    Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID
WHERE 

GROUP BY 
    Suppliers.CompanyName
ORDER BY 
    2 DESC;
```

I would like to only see the total sales over 10,000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the condition in a HAVING  clause:

```
SELECT  
  Suppliers.CompanyName, 
  SUM([Order Details].UnitPrice*Quantity)AS [Total sales]
FROM [Order Details] 
INNER JOIN 
Products ON products.ProductID= [Order Details] .ProductID
INNER JOIN
Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID= Suppliers.SupplierID
GROUP BY Suppliers.CompanyName
HAVING SUM([Order Details].UnitPrice*Quantity) > 10000
Order by 2 desc;
```

Comment: Copy/paste leftovers, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `HAVING` clause instead of a `WHERE` clause,

after `GROUP BY` as

```
HAVING SUM([Order Details].UnitPrice*Quantity) > 10000
```

in your SQL statement :

```
SELECT  Suppliers.CompanyName, SUM([Order Details].UnitPrice*Quantity) AS [Total sales]    
  FROM [Order Details]     
 INNER JOIN 
        Products ON products.ProductID= [Order Details] .ProductID
 INNER JOIN
        Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID= Suppliers.SupplierID
GROUP BY Suppliers.CompanyName
HAVING SUM([Order Details].UnitPrice*Quantity) > 10000
ORDER BY 2 desc
```